# Approximation of 2D-function with weight coefficients

Tags: c++, math

I need to approximate a table-defined 2D-function like that

```
x0 y0
x1 y1
...
xn yn
```

for every point I have a "weight" (root-mean-square error for this measure). I need to write a function like this:

```
typedef std::vector< double > DVector;
void approximate2D(
      const DVector & x
    , const DVector & y
    , const DVector & weights
    , double newMeasuredX
    , double newMeasuredY
    , double newMeasuredWeight
    , double & outApproximatedX
    , double & outApproximatedY
);
```

to get one value ( outApproximatedX; outApproximatedY ) depend on previous values and new measured value.

Root-mean-square (RMS) error should be used as follows: if a RMS error is minimal, then desired function should go close to this point, if a RMS error is maximal, then this point should be use with a minimal contribution.

Approximation should be linear (I think), since I know, that desired function is a straight line.

Googled about a half of a day, and did not found any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know `std::vector` is actually a class template and so you need to provide atleast one *type* argument when you `typedef` it?

Comment: Nawaz of course I know it. Just forgot. And... what's happening ? there is < double > in my post, but I have a copy of my post in clipboard - there is no type for vector... hmmm

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want the function to do. In a simple (or weighted) linear fit; what you want to calculate is the slope and offset of a line (`y = k x + m`), that passes as closely as possible to the given points. It doesn't make sense to return another point.

Comment: Check alglib http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/leastsquares.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To minimize the total squared closest distances to the line *a x* + *b y* = *r*, you can't use matrix equations, since the problem is no longer linear.

The distance to the line can be defined as follows. Then the function you want to minimize is *f*(*a*,*b*,*r*). This task is simplified somewhat when *a*<sup>2</sup> + *b*<sup>2</sup> = 1.

[image: Concepts]

If you expand that, it gets quite complex. I managed to break it down and simplify it somewhat.

[image: Calculations, calculations, calculations!]

To calculate this over many points (*O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>)) can get slow. There is however an easy optimization. Instead of calculating the sums over and over again, you can store partial results:

[image: Something that looks like an algorithm]

Here the σ variables are accumulators for common terms. Each time you want to add another point to the calculations, you update the 9 variables, and use those to calculate *a*, *b* and *r* as before.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a space-filling-curve either a Hilbert-Curve or a Peano-Curve. A sfc is a good approximation of a 2D or XD grid.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for MizardX. A great help. That is what I wrote ( if someone need :) )
http://liveworkspace.org/code/815e2cc0810ab8ef14951252cca3fbbf

P.S. I can't vote for MizardX (no reputation). Can somebody do it for me ?

Comment: You should know that the equation minimizes the squared vertical (y²) distance to the line, not the closest distance. To minimize the squared closest distance to the line, it'll require some more work. I could update the answer if this is what you want instead.

Comment: Ouh, I didn't know this. Of course I need to minimize a distances to desired line (x^2+y^2). Could you help me with that ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Discarded the matrix calculations, but now it uses the closest distance.